# Aggregate information when documents are inserted or deleted

Tags: mongodb

I have a database with a collection of documents which looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "548da5070b43957102000044"
    },
    "title": "some title",
    "link": "http://google.com",
    "group": "group_one",
    "priority_group": 0,
},
...
```

I have many different systems which insert such documents on collection and delete them.

I need to have another collection which aggregate the first one:

```
{
    "name": "group_one",
    "count": 10
},
{
    "name": "group_two",
    "count": 8
}
```

Is there any way to support this collection without rewriting all systems which is working with mongodb?  Something that works on the database level?  Like a triggers on the relation database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MongoDB doesn't have triggers. You will either have to run a job at regular intervals or update all the systems writing to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this in Python:

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()
documents = db.my.collection.find({},{"_id":0})

groups = []
new_doc = []

for document in documents:
    groups.append(document['group'])

for group in set(groups):
    dict0 = {'name':group,'count':groups.count(group)}    
    new_doc.append(dict0)

db.new.collection.insert(new_doc)
```

I've been able to insert dictionaries with around 500,000 relatively sizeable documents into MongoDB in less than 60 seconds. Running something like this at scheduled intervals may work for you.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using the aggregation framework?

Comment: No I didn't. There is nothing in your code which couldn't be done with an aggregation including running it at regular intervals.